# Простое с однородными или сложное предложение

Tags: синтаксис

> Ученые недавно послали к нему автоматических разведчиков, а в будущем
> будут отправлять все новую и новую технику.

Предложение простое с однородными членами или сложное, где вторая часть является неполным предложением с пропущенным подлежащим "ученые"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если верить автору школьных учебников Вере Васильевне Бабайцевой, в школах такие предложения рассматриваются как **простые, осложнённые однородными сказуемыми**.

**Из Бабайцевой («Синтаксис русского языка». М., 2015):**

> Предложения с однородными членами обычно рассматриваются как **1) простые предложения, осложненные однородными членами***; 2) сложные («слитные») предложения; 3) сложные предложения, но только если в них есть однородные глагольные сказуемые; 4) предложения, относящиеся к переходным синтаксическим единицам.
>
> *) **Эта точка зрения нашла отражение в школьной практике.**

Comment: Спасибо. Просто очень странным кажется противопоставление такого рода для обычного однородного ряда: послали, а будут отправлять (отправят). Не такая же картина, что, например, тут: "Я не люблю, а уважаю".

Comment: @
Татьяна Алексеевна  Союз  А здесь сопоставительный, а не противительный. И сопоставляются здесь не глаголы, а временные наречия  "недавно" и "в будущем".

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна, Вас смущают разновременные формы сказуемых в рассматриваемом предложении? Ну так время для однородности сказуемых не помеха. См., к примеру, такое предложение: _Для России Христос всегда **был, есть** и **будет**_. Здесь сказуемые стоят и в прошедшем, и в настоящем, и будущем времени, но тем не менее будут считаться однородными.

Comment: Более важным, чем временные формы сказуемых, для оппозиции **однородные сказуемые / сложное предложение** следует считать степень распространённости сказуемых. Но, как я понял из прочтения Бабайцевой, этот фактор при определении вида предложения – простое или сложное – в школе не учитывается…

Comment: @Слава Нет, не формы,а сама структура однородного ряда. Как будто она не может при союзе "а" выстроиться логично. При союзе "и" нормально звучит: послали и будут отправлять. Поэтому и подумала, что нужно еще одно подлежащее  - они, ученые.

Comment: "[Надя] пошла к себе наверх укладываться, а на другой день утром покинула город". В этом примере тоже такая замена уместна (пошла, а покинула), но в данном предложении что-то мешает так сделать.

Answer (score 1):

*Ученые **недавно послали** к нему автоматических разведчиков, **а в будущем будут отправлять** все новую и новую технику.*

1. Можно ли простое двусоставное предложение с **однородными** сказуемыми считать **сложным** предложением? В школе — **практически никогда!**

В школьных учебниках эта проблема решается **ОДНОЗНАЧНО** и обычно вопросов не вызывает: надо только правильно определить **основу предложения** как подлежащее + ряд однородных сказуемых. Разная морфология, а также  распространенность однородных сказуемых **не меняют грамматику.**

У **[Литневской](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p83_TOC_idp1659982784)** (краткий курс грамматики для школьников) про однородные члены сказано:

```
   Однородные члены соединяются сочинительными союзами или 
   просто перечислительной интонацией. В редких случаях 
   однородные члены могут быть соединены подчинительными 
   союзами (причинными, уступительными), например: Это была 
   полезная, потому что развивающая игра. Книга интересная, 
   хотя сложная.
   Однородными могут быть как главные, так и второстепенные 
   члены. Однородные члены могут иметь одинаковое или разное 
   МОРФОЛОГИЧЕСКОЕ выражение: Он часто был простужен и лежал 
   неделями в кровати.
```

2. Таким образом, про однородные сказуемые у Литневской **отдельно** не говорится ничего. А вот в **вузовском учебнике у Кустовой** этой теме посвящена **целая СТАТЬЯ**. Да, проблема существует, у лингвистов разные мнения по поводу однородных сказуемых. Но и там чтобы только задуматься **о статусе** предложения, нужна значительная **разобщенность** сказуемых.
3. Приводится такой **пример:** *На месте Наташи оказался Николай Иванович. Он **приобрел** свой прежний человеческий облик, но был чрезвычайно **мрачен** и даже, пожалуй, **раздражен*** (М. Булгаков).

Здесь союз ***И*** соединяет однородные именные части сказуемого, а союз ***НО***  скорее части сложносочиненного предложения ***ССП***, которое к тому же синонимично **СПП** с придаточным уступительным (хотя приобрел). Казалось бы, разобщенность **максимальная**, но и тогда говорится лишь **о приближении** простого предложения к сложному.

Таким образом, обозначена **ПЕРЕХОДНАЯ ЗОНА** зона,  но нет такого примера, когда можно окончательно сказать: это **сложное** предложение. Возможно, таких предложений  нет вообще.

4. В заданном предложении **разобщенность**, несомненно, присутствует. Однородные сказуемые значительно **распространены** и к тому же сопоставлены друг с другом во **временном** плане: наречия ***недавно и в будущем*** можно считать обстоятельственными детерминантами для каждого сказуемого.

Сравнить: "*[Надя] пошла к себе наверх укладываться, а **на другой день** утром покинула город".*  Здесь тоже разный временной план, но НЕТ обстоятельственного **детерминанта в начале** предложения.

```
  Из комментария: В этом примере тоже такая замена 
  уместна (пошла, а покинула), но в данном 
  предложении что-то МЕШАЕТ так сделать.
```

Казалось бы, по смыслу легко можно подставить местоимение ***они*** во вторую часть сообщения. Но нет! **Грамматика** — наука точная и формальная, и поэтому надо строго следовать **форме**. При наличии местоимения это будет уже **другое** предложение и другой синтаксис.